# restore specific db issue using pgbackrest

Tags: postgresql, pgbackrest

I have a question about how to backup a specific Database using pgbackrest:
the problem is when I tried to restore a selected db using `--include-db` option of pgbackrest i got just the selected db and built-in databases(postgres, template0 and template1) restored, and when i tried to connect another db after the restore I got this error :

```
**FATAL: relation mapping file "base/24581/pg_filenode.map" contains invalid data
Previous connection kept**
```

is there any solution that allows the restore of the whole db with the selected one without losing the other databases ??

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible according to the documentation of Include Database option:

> Include Database Option (--db-include) Restore only specified
>   databases. This feature allows only selected databases to be restored.
>   Databases not specifically included will be restored as sparse, zeroed
>   files to save space but still allow PostgreSQL to perform recovery.
>   After recovery the databases that were not included will not be
>   accessible but can be removed with the drop database command. NOTE:
>   built-in databases (template0, template1, and postgres) are always
>   restored.